# Conflicting types for 'function'

Tags: c

I'm learning C with "The C programming language" book. And I'm stucked with this error.
Here is the code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #define MAXLINE 1000 // Max input line length

  int getline(char line[], int maxline);
  void copy(char to[], char from[]);
  // Printing the longest input line
  int main()
  {
    int len; // Current line length, max line length ever seen
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
      if(len > max) // If current line length > previous max length - rewrite.
      {
        max = len;
        copy(longest, line);
      }
    }
    if(max > 0) // If there was a line
      printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
  }

  int getline(char s[],int lim) // return length of line
  {
    int c, i;

    for(i = 0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    {
      s[i] = c;
    }
    if(c == '\n')
    {
      s[i] = c;
      ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
  }

  void copy(char to[], char from[])
  {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
      ++i;
  }
```

This code is an example from the book :)
Trying to compile it on Linux: Linux 5.4.97-gentoo.
GCC version: 10.2.0.

Comment: if you paste the exact error with full text that compiler is throwing and read the same text  again you'll have the answer

Comment: Please include what the compilers reported to you... Anyway: getline is a function already defined taht is declared through you inclusion of stdio.h

Comment: OMG! My carelessness makes me stupid =\ Solved by renaming my function, because getline declared in stdio.h.

Comment: @Larry then accept the [answer by u__](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950689/14947044).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getline` is already declared in `<stdio.h>`. Change the method name to `my_getline`.